# Why does the "Right to Privacy" not apply to reparative therapy?

Tags: lgbt+, privacy, abortion

[Reparative Therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy#Self-determination), sometimes called Conversion Therapy or "Pray away the Gay" is a form of counseling which is sought by some people in order to change a perceived sexual orientation. While there is no evidence that it works, I was surprised to learn that the State Assembly of California has passed a bill [SB1172](http://www.sfgate.com/news/article/State-bans-gay-repair-therapy-for-minors-3906032.php) that criminalizes it.

What is surprising to me is that regardless of the effectiveness of the therapy, this would seem to be exactly the same "doctor-patient privacy" that is expected during an abortion. In both cases, this would seem to be a private medical procedure that is being barred. In both cases, there are studies which show both benefits and harm to the patients.

The question I have (and this is a serious question), what is the fundamental difference that allows California to ban one medical procedure but not another?

Comment: <<Removed Comments since they've degraded>>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The state can regulate and even ban any medical procedure, at least in California. For example, a proposed San Francisco ballot that would ban circumcision in San Francisco was struck down by the courts because [medical procedures are regulated by the state](http://www.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/07/28/circumcision.ban.voting/index.html).

However, **California did not ban gay conversion therapy**. If you look at the article to which you linked, you will find that California only banned the use of gay conversion therapy on minors. We know that the government can limit parental autonomy if it's being used abusively, and because this therapy [does not work, and may increase rates of suicide](http://www.apa.org/pi/lgbt/resources/therapeutic-response.pdf), we can reasonably consider forcing a child to attend conversion therapy abusive.

Comment: @AffableGeek, you might I wouldn't put too much weight on the "raparative therapy" increases suicide (Avi, does your linked "proper responses to sexual orientation" actually state that in any way?). For one, the overblown gay teens have [+3x the suicide rate](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9025/how-accurate-is-the-estimate-that-1-3-of-teen-suicides-are-homosexual) that is often reported is complete bunk.

Comment: @user1873 the link you provided links to another site for information, and that other site's neutrality is *highly* questionable.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_among_LGBT_youth is far less politically/ religiously motivated, IMHO.

Comment: It's the APA, Jeremy. They're a pretty reputable organization. And yeah user1873, do a ctrl-F for "suicid".

Comment: Yea, I'm OK citing the APA for psychological research. That's kinda of their thing.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, LiveScience is questionable? What estimate are you using from Wikipedia? The one that says, "It is impossible to know the exact suicide rate of LGBT youth because sexuality and gender minorities are often hidden and even unknown, particularly in this age group." or the one that makes up statistics out of thin air?

Comment: @user1873 specifically your link to the skeptics page, where the question was referencing a page from http://www.orthodoxytoday.org/...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, and the other link is not to orthodoxy, but to Joel Best's Danny Lies and Statistics book. There are several studies that reach the same conclusion that the 300x suicide rate is bunk.

Comment: @user1873 Funnily enough some 6 years after you linked to skeptics.. Someone posted an answer that connects to the CDC, and NCTE that shows that the +3X number is accurate and not overblown... Unless you are saying that the CDC and NCTE figures are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A state reserves the right to ban any practice, whether medical or not, where the consensus (or at least the majority) determines the potential harm outweighs the potential good.  In this respect, there are strict laws around testing experimental drugs and procedures, even if a particular drug or procedure may in fact save a person's life.  The right to privacy does not enter into the picture at all.

In addition, as I noted above, as homosexuality is not recognized as a disease or injury by any state (that I am aware of), it is therefore impossible to call a procedure designed to "fix" it a valid medical procedure.  Instead it belongs in the same category as homeopathic medicines, faith healing, and most dietary supplements where measurable results are not guaranteed, and are often not even expected.

Comment: Good point, but then why are those items you mentioned in your last sentence not banned too?

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: you should edit your answer to reflect that California did not ban the procedure, but just isn't allowing parents to use it on minors.

Comment: @Avi, I think my answer is generic enough to address the question without regard to the specific example provided.  I have no knowledge of the law and cannot speak knowledgeably about it one way or another... but the actual question asked, "what is the fundamental difference that allows California to ban one medical procedure but not another?" can be definitively answered *in absentia*.

Comment: @TTT, as mentioned in the first paragraph, this is based on the consensus of the legislative body... the current opinion seems to be that homeopathic medicines, faith healing, and most dietary supplements, while not necessarily *helpful*, are at least not *harmful*, while the procedure discussed by OP has been harshly criticized as potentially harmful by multiple medical and psychological bodies.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because Gay-to-straight therapy is very unpopular.  There are many many people who absolutely HATE the practice with a passion.  Telling people that homosexuality is a disease/condition that can be cured angers a great deal of people.

In a liberal state like California.  It's more unpopular than abortion is, the legislature felt the pressure from people who wanted it banned, so they banned it.

It's the same reason why things like medicinal marihuana is banned by the federal government.

There's really not much more to it than that.

Comment: While I cannot disagree that strong emotions are tied to this, I think banning the procedure stems from a desire to protect, rather than restrict.

Comment: While I agree people don't like the idea of it, it's also the fact that it is not medical sound science. As such, there's no reason medical legislation should apply to it.

Comment: @SamIam which is why I'm confused! To attempt to re-word my point: Reparative therapy is not seen as a valid medical procedure by the medical profession. As such, I'm not sure why medical legislation would apply to it. (As for pregnancy, it's a medical condition, though I make no arguments as what an 'illness' is).

Comment: @DVK: I thought your comment about pregnancy being an illness is funny, especially since I just read this today: "Federal law (Pregnancy Discrimination Act of 1978 which amended Title VII of the Civil Rights Act) requires employers with 15 or more employees to treat pregnancy as any other illness." (http://insurance.illinois.gov/HealthInsurance/maternity.asp)

Comment: @DVK I think a better parallel for the abortion argument you are making is something like elective surgery.  It's not medically necessary but it's still a medical treatment.  Reparative therapy is not a medical treatment - I think you would be hard pressed to identify a single medical school that teaches it.

Comment: @JNK - "normal" pregnancy doesn't require treatment (aside from folic acid) up until birth. Therefore comparing pregnancy with being sick is wrong.

Comment: @DVK he's not comparing pregnancy with being sick.  He's equating abortion with elective plastic surgery

Comment: @SamIam something like that. Obviously its a lot more complicated when it comes to abortion, and I'm not trying to say that those are equivalent procedures.

Comment: @DVK their point is that conversion therapy doesn't actually stop you from being gay.

Comment: @SamIam It's not legal because, like you said, it's not popular.  It's not applicable to be covered by right to privacy though because it's not actually medicine.  Faith healers aren't covered by privacy laws either, nor are new-age shaman types.  I'm not making a value judgement about either abortion or reparative therapy, but one is medicine and the other is not.  That's it.

Comment: @jnk what is "medicine"

Comment: @SamIam Medical science.  You know that stuff they teach in medical schools and publish papers about in medical journals like JAMA.  If you want to continue debating this please choose someone else, I've made my opinion very clear and whether you choose to comprehend or not is no longer my concern.

Comment: But if you want a source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy#United_States_2

Comment: I would think that psychiatric help would be considered a "medical treatment," and am fairly certain that those treatments are protected by HIPPA laws. I wonder why conversion therapy wouldn't be considered psychiatric help.

Comment: @user1873 per the wikipedia article, it's because "conversion therapy is ineffective, risky and can be harmful, and that there has been no scientific demonstration of its efficacy in the last forty years"

Comment: This is like saying "Telling people that Jews are soulless demons out to conquer the world so they can drain the blood of Christians angers a lot of people". Technically true, suggests that you think that the issue is people getting angry, and not, you know, the bigotry.